# What is a good way to track the timings of queries in postgresql without looking in the log file?

Tags: postgresql

I've got a function in a postgres database that does a lot of analysis; it consists of a succession of update and insert statements and eventually throws back some output. I'd like to figure out which statements execute slowly, without looking through the log files. (I'm much more comfortable with SQL than I am with, say, perl, to write date / time arithmetic queries in order to spot problems.)

I have a table, activity_log:

```
CREATE TABLE activity_log
(
action character varying(250),
action_date date,
action_tune time without time zone
);
```

then throughout my function, after each INSERT / UPDATE I write statements like

```
INSERT INTO activity_log (action_date, action_tune, action) 
VALUES (current_date, current_timestamp, 'INSERT to base_model');
```

So the function looks something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION rebucket(pos_control character varying, absolute_max_cpc numeric, absolute_max_bucket character varying)
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE qty INT;

BEGIN

INSERT INTO activity_log (action_date, action_tune, action) 
VALUES (current_date, current_timestamp, 'Off we go');

-- Do something that takes 5 minutes

INSERT INTO activity_log (action_date, action_tune, action) 
VALUES (current_date, current_timestamp, 'INSERT to base_model');

-- Then do something else that also takes about 5 minutes ...

INSERT INTO activity_log (action_date, action_tune, action) 
VALUES (current_date, current_timestamp, 'INSERT to diagnostics');

END 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I've got away with this in other databases in the past, but when I try this approach in Postgres (9.1 on Windows 7), then whenever I run the whole function the date and time in activity_log is exactly the same for every statement within the function: in the example above,

```
SELECT * FROM activity_log
```

gets me

```
Off we go              2013-05-13  12:33:23:386
INSERT to base_model   2013-05-13  12:33:23:386
INSERT to diagnostics  2013-05-13  12:33:23:386
```

(The function takes from 5 minutes to an hour to run, depending on what parameters we feed it, and it has upwards of 20 different statements within there, so it seems highly unlikely that *every* statement completed within the same 1/100th of a second.)

Why is that?

Comment: Check out the pg_stat_statements module: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Logging_Difficult_Queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp you are using always gives the start of the current transaction. If you look in the [manuals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) you will see that you want `clock_timestamp()`.